# How to handle react-navigation tabbaritem click?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

What I want is when user is not logged in click on the tabbarItem, then switch to login navigator!
So how can I handle tabbarItem click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `tabBarOnPress` options mentioned in `react-navigation`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html It may help you to achieve what you need.

Update: You can also declare `navigationOptions` as a function like this, to get access to `navigation` object:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: event => {
      navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions...)
      // event.defaultHandler(); // This is the default handler from react-navigation (go to the tab)
    },
    ...otherOptions
  })
```

Comment: Yes, How can I let it run my custom action? like navigate to other page!

Comment: @DavidLee If it works I would appreciate if you can mark my answer as answered

Comment: Sure, Thanks a lot!